# revive vs revivify

Tags: synonyms

I recently stumbled upon the word **"revivify"**.
As a verb, it seems to be a synonym for **"revive"**.

Is it? Or are there any differences between the 2 words?

And is it usual to have synonymous words with the same root?

I googled it to find this
https://wikidiff.com/revive/revivify
but that didn't explain enough. So, I'm asking my first question here.

Comment: In some role playing games, revive means to restore consciousness and revivify means to bring back to life (from death). In what context was this used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In contemporary English, the difference between *revive* and *revivify* is generally that *revivify* is unlikely to be used for people or animals. For events, activities, organizations, and so forth, *revive* and *revivify* are very close synonyms.

[Cambridge Dictionary's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revivify) definition for *revivify*:

> to give new energy and strength to **an event or activity:**
> *A leader with real charisma is needed to revivify the political party.* (boldface mine)

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revivify):

> To revivify **a situation, event, or activity** means to make it more active, lively, or efficient. (boldface mine)

According to the OED, when it first came into English, it could be applied to people or animals. And it is still used for the sense of bringing corpses back to life.

> *transitive.* To reanimate or restore to life. Also: to raise from the dead or from the grave.
>
> 1883   H. Drummond *Nat. Law in Spiritual World*   The biologist cannot devitalise a plant or an animal and revivify it again.
> 1921 *Jrnl. Soc. Oriental Res.*   The kings, the offspring of the gods, were destined to die, to be revivified, and to live in heaven.
> 2001   M. W. Dickie *Magic & Magicians in Greco-Roman World*  Public displays consist in healing the lame, curing blindness and revivifying corpses.

Except for bringing corpses back to life, none of the OED's citations since 1900 is used for animals or people.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your assertion on revivify. Revivify means: to give new life, energy, or spirit to something or **somebody.**

Comment: @Ubi hatt: if you want to define *revivify* so as to encompass all of its uses for the last 300 years, that's certainly a good definition. *Cambridge Dictionary* and *Collins Dictionary* seem to leave *somebody* out of the definition, which agrees with my perception of its use in 21st century English.

Comment: If you wish, you can add [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=revive%2C+revivify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crevive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crevivify%3B%2Cc0) as well. It shows that, revivify is less commonly used compared to revive.

Comment: I can find citations for *revivify* that do refer to bodies. Smithsonian, May 2015, Vol. 46 Issue 2, p44-5: Nor does he expect to get there preserved in alcohol or a freezer; despite the claims made by advocates of oryonics, he says, the ability to **revivify a frozen body** " isn't really on the horizon. "

Comment: Queer Pier, Summer 2013, Vol. 72 Issue 2, p106-113. "They, too, **try to revivify abject bodies**, removing them from the cold, dark tombs of the stacks, bringing them into the light" (Body figurative of texts and other objects of research.)

Comment: @Taliesin: *Revivify* is indeed also used for bringing dead bodies back to life today, as I mention in my answer.

Comment: @PeterShor True, though a frozen body is not a dead body. I can also find examples for revivifying human parts, like skin or organs, in roughly the sense of renewal or rejuvenation. I agree that the general pattern is for revivify to take events or situations as its object, but animals and humans can also be objects even in present usage, and not just referring to dead bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Sudheeshix welcome to EL&U.

'Revivify', as you stated is indeed a word, similar to revive, but I have never heard it used in speech or the written word.

```
Revivify: Verb - to give new energy and strength to an event or activity:
```

"A leader with real charisma is needed to revivify the political party."

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revivify

```
Revive: Verb - to come or bring something back to life, health, existence, or use:
```

"to revive someone's hopes/confidence/fortunes"
"My plants revived as soon as I gave them some water."
"A hot shower and a cup of tea will revive you."
"Traditional skills are being revived."

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revive

It appears that to 'revive' is to bring back to life, whereas 'revivify' is to give new energy or strength'.

WikiDiff explains the difference here: https://wikidiff.com/revive/revivify

As verbs the difference between revive and revivify is that revive is to return to life; to recover life or strength; to live anew; to become reanimated or reinvigorated while revivify is to reanimate, bring back to life.

Comment: This is ***not*** the difference. [Oxford Dictionaries Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revivify): Give new life or vigour to.